# Finding Hash's in text files

Tags: python, authentication

I'm am trying to verify users using a text document but not having much success. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Here is my code. What I want to do is have have python look on the line which contains the hash and then verify the hash. It is able to verify the first hash but nothing after that. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
def passwordVerify():
    global hashOne
    f = open("maindata.txt")
    s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    numberOne = userConfirm + 2
    numberTwo = userConfirm + 1
    for line in islice(f, numberTwo, numberOne):
        hashOne = line
    hashStripped = str.rstrip(hashOne)
    hashchecker = sha256_crypt.verify(passWord, hashStripped)
    f.close()
    if hashchecker is True:
        loggedIn()

    else:
        print "Please try again!"
        time.sleep(2.5)
        userLogin()


def userRegister():
    screenClear()
    print "!King of Hearts Registration System!"
    realName = raw_input("What is your real name: ")
    userName = raw_input("Choose a Username: ")
    passWord = getpass.getpass("Please enter a password: ")
    passHash = sha256_crypt.encrypt(passWord)
    writeUser = "\n" + userName + "\n"
    writePass = passHash
    userDB = open("maindata.txt", "a")
    userDB.write(str(writeUser))
    userDB.write(str(writePass))
    userDB.close()
    print passHash
    userLogin()
```

Comment: Your hash value as read from the file likely includes the newline character at the end of the line. You should strip this off before using it using e.g. `str.rstrip()`.

Comment: But it also won't verify newly registered users, how do i fix this?

Comment: That's a different question, and nobody is going to wade into that ocean of code to fix it anyway.